# Is there any issue adding a DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfoChanged event to the OnStart of a XF app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My app has this code:

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfoChanged += OnMainDisplayInfoChanged 
    }

    private void OnMainDisplayInfoChanged(object sender, DisplayInfoChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetDeviceInfo();
        SetResourceDimensions();
    }
```

I have read that with Android the OnStart can be called multiple times.  Can someone please tell me if this will cause a problem for the code that I have where I register the OnMainDisplayInfoChanged method.

Comment: You could add the line `DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfoChanged -= OnMainDisplayInfoChanged ` before `+=` .

Comment: Oh that's a good idea !

Comment: I will post it as answer with more details if it is helpful to you , could you accept it ?

Comment: yes I can accept that

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT - Thanks for your answer.  I added a comment after your answer. Can you check that comment when you have time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you case , since the method `OnStart()` will been called multi-times .  The method `OnMainDisplayInfoChanged`  will maybe been called multi-times at same time . Because the method list of  `MainDisplayInfoChanged`  has repetitive method .

So we could remove it from `MainDisplayInfoChanged` before we add it .

```
bool IsFirstLoad = true;
```

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
   base.OnStart();

   

   if(!IsFirstLoad)
   {
       DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfoChanged -= OnMainDisplayInfoChanged 
   }

   DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfoChanged += OnMainDisplayInfoChanged;
   IsFirstLoad = false ;
}
```

Comment: Would it be easier to just put DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfoChanged += OnMainDisplayInfoChanged; inside the if statement so that it was just added once?

Comment: The if statement is select-able , you could  `-=` directly . But `-=` is necessary because we could not customize `MainDisplayInfoChanged` .